# How do I bypass #value! error for a filter() with multiple arguments when one argument is blank?

Tags: google-sheets

I have this formula to combine and filter multiple sheets if a certain column has "Y" in it:

`=SORT({filter(Bryson!A4:S502, REGEXMATCH(Bryson!Q4:Q502, "Y"));filter(David!A4:S502, REGEXMATCH(David!Q4:Q502, "Y"));filter(Justin!A4:S502, REGEXMATCH(Justin!Q4:Q502, "Y"))},18,1)`

Multiple people work within their named sheets, 9 total, and data is wiped weekly. Problem is, when somebody has zero hits for the filter, the entire equation errors with VALUE#. How do I make it ignore arguments when there is no matches?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Google Sheets and Microsoft have different feature sets and require different answers. Your formula looks like its from Google Sheets so I am assuming that platform. Edited that tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the ranges "the other way":

```
=sort( 
  filter( 
    { Bryson!A4:S; David!A4:S; Justin!A4:S },
    regexmatch({ Bryson!Q4:Q; David!Q4:Q; Justin!Q4:Q }, "Y") 
  ), 
  18, 1 
)
```

Alternatively, use `query()`:

```
=query( 
  { Bryson!A4:S; David!A4:S; Justin!A4:S },
  "where Col17 contains 'Y' order by Col18", 0 
)
```

Comment: This works, thank you! I'm using filter instead of query to maintain a hyperlink unique to each row